# How to show $\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \frac{\sec\theta}{2\tan^2\theta \space+\space 1}\,\Bbb d\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: integration

I was doing some calculations to get magnetic field in square solenoid (that has $N$ turns of current carrying square loops wound on some material), and need to find this integration :

$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \frac{\sec\theta}{2\tan^2\theta+1}\,\Bbb d\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}.$$

But I don't know how to even start.

Can someone please explain it to me?

Comment: I would start with $$2\tan^2 \theta +1 = \tan^2 \theta +\tan^2 \theta +1 =\sec^2 \theta -1 +\sec^2 \theta.$$ Actually forget that... multiply integrand by $$\frac{\cos^2 \theta}{\cos^2 \theta}$$ You should come to $$\int \frac{\cos \theta}{\sin^2 \theta +\sin^2 \theta +\cos^2 \theta} = \int \frac{\cos \theta}{\sin^2 \theta +1}$$ Ill leave the rest to you.

Comment: Try the [tangent half-angle substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution). BTW it's $\dfrac\pi2$, not $\dfrac1{2\pi}$.

Answer (score 7):

Easy. First note that;
\begin{align*}
\frac{\sec{\theta}}{2\tan^2{\theta}+1}\text{d}\theta
&=\frac{\sec{\theta}}{2\frac{\sin^2{\theta}}{\cos^2{\theta}}+1}\text{d}\theta\\
&=\frac{\sec{\theta}}{\frac{2\sin^2{\theta}+\cos^2{\theta}}{\cos^2{\theta}}}\text{d}\theta\\
&=\frac{\sec{\theta}\times\cos^2{\theta}}{2\sin^2{\theta}+\cos^2{\theta}}\text{d}\theta\\
&=\frac{\cos{\theta}}{1+\sin^2{\theta}}\text{d}\theta\\
&=\frac{1}{1+\sin^2{\theta}}\frac{\text{d}\sin{\theta}}{\text{d}\theta}\text{d}\theta\\
&=\frac{1}{1+\sin^2{\theta}}\text{d}\sin{\theta}.
\end{align*}
So we have;
\begin{align*}
\int\frac{\sec{\theta}}{2\tan^2{\theta}+1}\text{d}\theta
&=\int\frac{1}{1+\sin^2{\theta}}\text{d}\sin{\theta}.
\end{align*}
Let $s=\sin{\theta}$. Then we have;
\begin{align*}
\int{\frac{1}{1+s^2}\text{d}s}.
\end{align*}
Let $k=\arctan(s)$ so that $\tan{k}=s=\sin{\theta}$. So we have;
\begin{align*}
\int\frac{1}{1+s^2}\text{d}s
&=\int\frac{1}{1+\tan^2{k}}\text{d}s\\
&=\int\frac{\cos^2{k}}{\sin^2{k}+\cos^2{k}}\text{d}s\\
&=\int\cos^2{k}\times\text{d}\tan{k}\\
&=\int\cos^2{k}\times\frac{\text{d}\tan{k}}{\text{d}k}\text{d}k\\
&=\int\cos^2(k)\times\sec^2(k)\text{d}k\\
&=\int\text{d}k\\
&=k+C.
\end{align*}

But $k=\tan^{-1}(\sin{\theta})$. So the answer is $\tan^{-1}(\sin{\theta})+C$. Now, the numerical answer must be;
$$\tan^{-1}\left(\sin{\frac{\pi}{2}}\right)-\tan^{-1}\left(\sin{-\frac{\pi}{2}}\right)=\frac{\pi}{4}-\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}.$$

Comment: Thanks you! it helped me a lot

Answer (score 3):

$$
\begin{aligned}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sec \theta}{2 \tan ^2 \theta+1} d \theta = & \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\cos \theta}{2 \sin ^2 \theta+\cos ^2 \theta} d \theta \\
= & \int_{-1}^1 \frac{d s}{s^2+1} \text {, where } s=\sin \theta \\
= & {\left[\tan ^{-1} s\right]_{-1}^1 } \\
= & \frac{\pi}{4}-\left(-\frac{\pi}{4}\right) \\
= & \frac{\pi}{2}
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 0):

For the [Weierstrass substitution approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#The_substitution) you get
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sec(x)}{2\tan^2(x)+1}\, \mathrm{d}x &= \int_{-1}^{1}\frac{\left(\frac{1+t^2}{1-t^2} \right)}{2\left(\frac{2t}{1-t^2} \right)^2+1}\frac{2}{\left(1+t^2\right)}\, \mathrm{d}t\\
& = \int_{-1}^{1}\frac{1}{\left(\frac{2t}{1+t^2}\right)^2 +1}\frac{2(1-t^2)}{(1+t^2 )^2}\, \mathrm{d}t\\
& \overset{\color{purple}{u = 2t/(1+t^2)}}{=} \int_{-1}^{1}\frac{1}{u^2+1}\, \mathrm{d}u\\
& = \frac{\pi}{2}
\end{align*}